# Shuffle manager for Apache Spark and S3 compatible storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, shuffle

Is there a way to modify spark properties (without adding external plugins) in order to write the shuffle data in a s3 bucket ?
We are currently running with spark v3.1.0.

There is a shuffle pluging ([spark-s3-shuffle](https://github.com/IBM/spark-s3-shuffle)) but only available from 3.2.0 and we don't want to modify the spark version.

Thanks a lot

Comment: That plugin is open source, so you can try to clone its repository locally, modify the `sparkVersion` on [build.sbt](https://github.com/IBM/spark-s3-shuffle/blob/main/build.sbt), and refer to that in your project's dependencies.

Comment: What on earth for?

Comment: Spark 3.1 has a slightly different API compared to Spark 3.2+. There's now a version for 3.1.x available here: https://github.com/IBM/spark-s3-shuffle/tree/spark-3.1